# F#: pattern matching on base types

Tags: f#

I have a series of validation functions I want to put into an array to execute:

```
type result = {D: int; E: int; F: int; G: int}

type InvalidReason =
| AAA
| BBB
| CCC
| DDD
| EEE

type Validation =
| Valid
| Invalid of InvalidReason

let validators = [|AAA; BBB; CCC; DDD; EEE|]

let validateStuff result =
    validators
    |> Array.map(fun v -> v result)
    |> Array.contains(Validation.Invalid _)
```

The problem is that last line of code. I am getting an "Unexpected value _ in the expression." The following does work

```
|> Array.contains(Validation.Valid)
|> Array.contains(Validation.Invalid InvalidReason.AAA)
```

But I don't want to spell out each of the sub types for InvalidReasons. Is there some syntax I am overlooking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `Array.contains` takes a value and checks if that value is in the array. What you're trying to do is to give it a whole bunch of values to check. Well, this won't work: the function only takes one. And it doesn't help that there is no syntax like that in F# :-)

You might use another function that takes multiple values, but a better way to accomplish what you want is to use a function that takes a predicate - [`Array.exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array.exists%5b%27t%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d). Make yourself a predicate to check if a value is "invalid":

```
let isInvalid x = match x with
    | Valid -> false
    | Invalid _ -> true
```

And pass it to `Array.exists`:

```
let validateStuff result = 
    validators 
    |> Array.map(fun v -> v result) 
    |> Array.exists isInvalid
```

Or you could even put that function inline:

```
let validateStuff result = 
    validators 
    |> Array.map(fun v -> v result) 
    |> Array.exists ( fun x -> match x with
            | Valid -> false
            | Invalid _ -> true )
```

Or even shorter, using the `function` keyword:

```
let validateStuff result = 
    validators 
    |> Array.map(fun v -> v result) 
    |> Array.exists ( function | Valid -> false | Invalid _ -> true )
```

Or even shorter, getting rid of as much noise as possible:

```
let validateStuff result = 
    validators 
    |> Array.map(fun v -> v result) 
    |> Array.exists ( function Invalid _ -> true | _ -> false )
```